# How to bind data to DTO attribute based on a condition?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to bind data to a variable  known as `CurrentControlled` that is defined in my DTO (Data transfer object), The issue is that i want to assign a string based on what data is returned from the database. In this case i have a table in my database known as `RiskActions` which has a column known as `ActionCompleteDate`, if the data inside `ActionCompleteDate` has date value in it than the string assigned to `CurrentControlled` should be 'Current', whereas if there is no date present inside `ActionCompleteDate` then the value for `CurrentControlled` should be Controlled.

I have tried assigning a condition to `CurrentControlled` but for some reason the compiler gives me an error.

```
var actions = dataContext.RiskInstances.Where(riskInstancePredicate.Compile());
actions = actions
    .OrderBy(a => a.RiskInstanceID2)
    .ThenBy(a=> a.Issue.Question);

List<RiskDTO> results = actions
    .Select(ra => new RiskDTO
    {
        CurrentControlled = if(ra.RiskActions.Where(m => m.ActionCompleteDate == null)) {
            TerminologyFactor.Parse("{Current}",TerminologyFactor.RMMonitor)
        }
        else {
            TerminologyFactor.Parse("{Controlled}",TerminologyFactor.RMMonitor)
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator). Also, this is a guess because I don't know your data structure here, but you likely need to use `Any` instead of `Where` as it returns a boolean you can use as the condition:

```
List<RiskDTO> results = actions
    .Select(ra => new RiskDTO
    {
        CurrentControlled = ra.RiskActions.Any(m => m.ActionCompleteDate == null))
            ? TerminologyFactor.Parse("{Current}",TerminologyFactor.RMMonitor)
            : TerminologyFactor.Parse("{Controlled}",TerminologyFactor.RMMonitor)
    }
```